# Installing the correct Nvidia driver for 18.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

This question has been asked a lot of times but I still can resolve my issue. I'm currently using a **GTX 1060** and I get tearing on only one of my three monitors, sometimes 2 monitors. First I thought it was an issue with using **DisplayPort** but after swapping the cables around it didn't change at all.

**What I tried:**

`ubuntu-driver devices` returns:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv0000196Esd0000119Fbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

The issue is that by installing this recommended driver upon restarting only one monitor is recognized and there is only choose one resolution.

I also tried to install the driver directly from Nvidia and execute the `.run` file, no success.

Some guides say to use bumblebee other to install the driver directly from Nvidia other from a 3rd party. None of them I tried really work. Even Nvidia X Server doesn't seem to be responding.

I also reinstalled Ubuntu several times.

Comment: Why you don't try install driver from Ubuntu GUI like **Software & Updates** -> **Additional Drivers** ?

Comment: When I arrive to the **Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers** I get two choises - NVIDIA driver metapackage & X.Org X serer - Nouveau display driver. Should I use the NVIDIA one ?